# rpcinfo don't show nfs_acl

Tags: linux, mount, nfs

I have a mounting problem with a Solaris 2.7 and linux SuSE SLES 12 machine. The Solaris machine should mount a NFS from a SLES 12 machine. I have two SLES 12 SP4 machine running. The error I got from the machine that is not working is: "NFS getacl failed for server xxxxx: error 9 (RPC: Programm/Version mismatch)". On the other machine the mount works fine.

I search and tried a few things (including NFS Versions, export and mount options) but the main different between the machine that is working and the machine that is not working is the output of the rpcinfo -p.
The machine that is working show the entries:

```
    100003    2   tcp   2049  nfs
    100003    3   tcp   2049  nfs
    100003    4   tcp   2049  nfs
    100227    2   tcp   2049  nfs_acl
    100227    3   tcp   2049  nfs_acl
    100003    2   udp   2049  nfs
    100003    3   udp   2049  nfs
    100003    4   udp   2049  nfs
    100227    2   udp   2049  nfs_acl
    100227    3   udp   2049  nfs_acl
```

And on the machine that is not working:

```
    100003    2   tcp   2049  nfs
    100003    3   tcp   2049  nfs
    100003    4   tcp   2049  nfs
    100003    2   udp   2049  nfs
    100003    3   udp   2049  nfs
```

all entries with 100227 nfs_acl are missing.

The command lsmod show that nfs_acl is in the kernel included. Which settings/switch/option i'm missing to activate the missing acl_nfs. I bet this would solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. On the machine I got the error I needed to try out a new software package and therefore a vendor change to openSUSE of a few packages are made and the kernel was changed too! Both kernels 4.x and 5.3.x were installed parallel and 5.3.x was active. And this combination result in the problem. I checked for updates and realize that I stuck at this version. There are newer versions of 5.3 and 4.x available but I was not able to install them.
I fetched all packages from the openSUSE vendor and changed it back and deinstall the 5.3 kernel. After rebooting the 4.x kernel and upgrading it to 4.12.14 the nfs_acl are available and the solaris NFS works fine.